# ngnix proxy https request to subfolders

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have several external facing web applications behind nginx like so:

> https://app1.mycompany.com --> server1:8080/app1
>
> https://app2.mycompany.com --> server2:8080/app2
>
> https://app2.mycompany.com --> server2:8080/app3

I requested to update nginx configuration to proxy using sub-folder instead and was told by our sysadmin that this would not be possible under https since the request url itself is encrypted.  Our sysadmin is very knowledgeable and security-minded, and what he said makes sense. However, I have worked on federated systems (as app developer) where https request to sub-folders are proxied to separate applications.  Can someone help me understand what type of setup would be necessary to achieve the following:

> https://www.mycompany.com/app1 --> server1:8080/app1
>
> https://www.mycompany.com/app2 --> server2:8080/app2
>
> https://www.mycompany.com/app3 --> server2:8080/app3

Comment: The key to configuring this reverse proxy is that nginx will have to have the SSL certificate for `www.mycompany.com` and handle the SSL encryption.  Then it will have access to the decrypted URL (and all the other decrypted data).

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like the what's below. Just specify the folders for the HTTPS reverse proxy address using the `location` directive, and the folders for the internal locations using the `proxy_pass` directive address.

```
server {

        listen          <ip_address>:443;
        ssl             on;
        server_name     <domain_name>;

        ### SSL cert files ###
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/local.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/local.key;

        ### Add SSL specific settings here ###


        ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers          RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        keepalive_timeout    60;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;

        location /app1 {
                proxy_pass  http://<internal_ip>:8080/app1;

                proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                add_header              Front-End-Https   on;

                proxy_redirect     off;
        }

        location /app2 {
                proxy_pass  http://<internal_ip>:8080/app2;

                proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                add_header              Front-End-Https   on;

                proxy_redirect     off;

        location /app3 {
                proxy_pass  http://<internal_ip>:8080/app3;

                proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                add_header              Front-End-Https   on;

                proxy_redirect     off;
        }
}
```

Comment: It is better to append the `ssl` keyword at the end of `listen` directive, that is the new preferred format.